# How to delete with these conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-delete

How can I delete rows which meet several conditions from a table without primary key? (actually the primary key is formed by every column)

After so many tries I have a code that first creates a temporary table where it inserts the rows I want to delete and finally I try to delete the rows from original table which meet the conditions comparing to temporary table.

But it gives me the error about cannot linking the several parts identifier #temp.idCarga

Maybe it's easy but I have been trying so much time and I cannot focus properly.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
(
    CC int,
    idCarga int, 
    Tipo nvarchar(50),
    Importe float,
    Bloque nvarchar(50),
    idsistema int
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP(CC,idCarga,Importe,Bloque,Tipo,IdSistema)
select distinct CI.CC,CI.idCarga,CI.Importe,CI.Bloque,CI.Tipo,CI.idSistema
from CONT_INGRESOS_InformeMayor CI
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT idCarga,CC,Bloque,Importe,TIpo
    FROM CONT_INGRESOS_InformeMayor
) CI2 
    ON CI.CC = CI2.CC 
    AND CI.Bloque = CI2.Bloque 
    AND CI.TIpo <> CI2.Tipo
WHERE CI.idCarga = @idCarga 
    AND CI2.idCarga = @idCarga 
    AND CI.Importe = 0

DELETE 
FROM CONT_INGRESOS_InformeMayor 
WHERE idCarga = #temp.idCarga 
    AND tipo = #temp.tipo 
    AND importe = #temp.importe 
    and bloque = #temp.bloque
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a join on your `DELETE`. Try this:

```
DELETE _d
FROM CONT_INGRESOS_InformeMayor AS _d
INNER JOIN #temp AS _t
    ON _d.idCarga = _t.idCarga 
    AND _d.tipo = _t.tipo 
    AND _d.importe = _t.importe 
    AND _d.bloque = _t.bloque
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `DELETE` is missing a `JOIN` to your `#temp` table

```
DELETE t1
FROM CONT_INGRESOS_InformeMayor t1
INNER JOIN #temp t
    ON t1.idCarga = t.idCarga 
        AND t1.tipo = t.tipo 
        AND t1.importe = t.importe 
        and t1.bloque = t.bloque
```

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, you could try deleting the rows without involving a temporary table:

```
DELETE FROM CI
from CONT_INGRESOS_InformeMayor CI
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT idCarga,CC,Bloque,Importe,TIpo
    FROM CONT_INGRESOS_InformeMayor
) CI2 
    ON CI.CC = CI2.CC 
    AND CI.Bloque = CI2.Bloque 
    AND CI.TIpo <> CI2.Tipo
WHERE CI.idCarga = @idCarga 
    AND CI2.idCarga = @idCarga 
    AND CI.Importe = 0
```